# Prove $\partial (S \cup T)= \partial(S) \cup \partial(T)$ given only two definitions for boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Given these two definitions for ***boundary***, where $K \subseteq X$ and $(X,d)$ is a metric space:

- $\partial K = \bar K \cap \overline {X \setminus K}$
- $\partial K = \{ x\in X \space | \space \forall r>0, B(x;r)\cap K \neq \emptyset \space \space and \space \space B(x;r) \setminus K \neq \emptyset\}$

where $\bar K =  \{\space x\in X \space | \space \forall r>0, B(x;r)\cap K\neq \emptyset \}$ is the *closure* of $K$.

Prove that, given the metric space $(X,d)$ and $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $X$, when $\bar {S} \cap \bar {T} = \emptyset$, then $\partial (S \cup T)= \partial(S) \cup \partial(T)$.

I'm trying to prove this with set equality. This is what I have so far:

$\partial (S \cup T) = \overline {S \cup T} \cap \overline {X\setminus (S\cup T)}$

$=(\bar S \cup \bar T) \cap \overline{(X\setminus S) \cap (X\setminus T)}$

$\subseteq (\bar S \cup \bar T) \cap \Big(\overline{(X\setminus S)} \cap \overline {(X\setminus T)}\Big)$

From here I'm not sure what do next.
If I'm on the right track, I could use help continuing.

If I'm not on the right track with this, what should I do instead?

Comment: You are in the right track. The last step requires justification. You need the fact that $\bar S \cap \bar T$ is empty for this. Once this is done you get $\partial (S \cup T)$ contained in the union of $\bar S \cap \overline {X \setminus S}$ and  $\bar T \cap \overline {X \setminus T}$ which proves that $\partial (S \cup T) \in {\partial S} \cup \partial T$. The reverse inclusion also requires a proof and the hypothesis that $\bar S \cap \bar T$ is empty is needed again.

Answer (score 0):

As $\overline S$ and T are disjoint, $\overline S \subseteq X - T \subseteq \overline {X - T}.$
Similarly with $\overline T$ and S.

That will finish one containment.
The reverse containment will require another proof.